# How to put synchronization delay between two test steps in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

When I put in manual delay sometimes the test fails since the delay time is too less. Sometimes it works

Comment: have yo ugot an example of what you're trying to do  ? (steps, etc.)

Comment: you may loop awaiting the result of your previous step ... but as long as you don't provide more information, I can't help, sorry